# How to set default value for select field in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a default value for a `reactjs` `select` option field when the page loads for the first time.

default value should be: `Select Marital Status`

But It doesn't set I tried many times. Can someone help me?

This is what I tried:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      marital_status: "Select Marital Status",
    };
  }

  onChange_marital_status = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        marital_status: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

and this is the field:

```
<InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
Select Marital Status
</InputLabel>
<Select
defaultValue={this.state.marital_status}
value={this.state.marital_status}
onChange={this.onChange_marital_status.bind(this)}
>
<MenuItem value={0}>Divorced</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={1}>Married</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={2}>Single</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

It is showing like below when the page loads (attached screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You add more option Select Marital Status
The 
the default value for this.state.martial_status should be like this

```
this.state = {
      marital_status: -1
    };
```

Comment: Are you using a library or something? Material-UI has an element called MenuItem which turns into `selected` if you add it like <MenuItem selected>foo</MenuItem> or <MenuItem selected={true condition}>Item</MenuItem>